# Need to id a parent comment to display its responses below

Tags: php, html, sql

I have two comment forms. One comment form "parent" and another response form.

How can I

- Let the script know what what response belongs to x parent comment
- Also maintain what responses below x comment at the point of INSERTING and SELECTing to display.

I have the INSERT for parent comment ready. But for the response INSERT I know there is a extra field  that will save the id of the comment parent so the resposne comment can display below it's parent comment.

From where can I take the id for that comment form and insert it in the database for responses comments.

Responses comments form

```
<form align="left" id="bring" action="profile.php?id='. $uid .'" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="message_from">
<textarea name="comment_field_2" type="text" id="text2" rows="3" style="width:100%; height:30px;"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" id="parent_comment" name="comments" value="23" />
<input id="bringinput" name="submit" type="button" value="submit" align="left" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please consider improving your question. Your question in its current form is a bit confusing. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section on ways to improve your question. Are you talking about a system like SO's where you have Questions and Answers (answers tagged to questions)?

Comment: @JohnP give fello a break its only fello's...37th question!?

Comment: lol thanks, I still learning the language

Comment: @fello my apologies that wasn't very nice. For what its worth the problem is with the formatting not the language

Comment: @fello we understand that not everyone speaks English as a first lang (I don't either). But we need the questions to be clear so that we can help you :) The links I mentioned in my comments will help you clean up your question which will let us help more effectively

Comment: @fello to make amends I've tried to help in  reformatting your question. If you click on the link above my name and next to edited you can see the history and roll it back if you want.

Comment: Really it is really important to update my language to the level you guys can understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you must have:

- in table holding comments, the field **parent_comment_id**
- in the **form (html) of the child response** a hidden field containing the id of the parent post (**parent_comment_id**)
- at the application level, when you receive a comment post, if there is the parent_comment_id with some value, you store it, otherwise, this is a main comment and not a response to something

I hope I understood your question correctly.